# Finding cell address from cell value

Tags: excel-formula

I have determined the minimum and maximum values of a column in an Excel spreadsheet using MINIMUM and MAXIMUM. Now, I want to find the corresponding cell addresses for those values. Is there an Excel function I can use?

Comment: Why?  To what end do you need the address?  Are you then going to use it to lookup another cell?  If so then there are ways to do it in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple one, but this will work if your range is vertical:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(<Range>), <Range>, 0) + ROW(<Range>) - 1, <ColNum>)
```

And this will work if it's horizontal (just FYI, since you said your range was a column):

```
=ADDRESS(<RowNum>, MATCH(MIN(<Range>), <Range>, 0) + COLUMN(<Range>) - 1)
```

(Obviously you'll have to replace anything in angle brackets with some actual values or formulas.)

I agree with [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418867/finding-cell-address-from-cell-value#comment58538443_35418867) though; depending on what you want to use the address for, there's a good chance there's a better formula for your purposes.

*Disclaimer: I work on Ubuntu, so these have been tested in LibreOffice rather than Excel. There may be some discrepancies in implementations.*